# Set Icon based on value from Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I am binding a `Grid` to a collection and inside the collection is another collection.

If the second collection has any values I would like to show an icon in the grid row.

What is the best way to do this in WPF? 
At the moment I am binding to a property called `HasValues` which checks the collection. But this does not work as its on the entire collection.

```
    public bool HasValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Collection.SubCollection.Any() &&
                this.Collection.SubCollection.First() != null &&
                this.Collection.SubCollection.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

the xaml looks like this

```
<Custom:CustomGridIconButton Icon="{StaticResource ShowIcon}" 
    Visibility="{Binding HasValues}" />
```

but what I would like to do is based on the index in the grid check if that index has values in the sub cllection...

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upload the  xaml code of your `Grid` ...

Comment: Why are checking for `this.Collection.SubCollection.Any()` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your `bool` property into whatever data type that you have in your outer collection then it can reflect whether its inner collection has any values in it. Of course, I have no idea about your actual data types because you failed to show us them, so I can only make assumptions here - I trust that you can adopt this idea to your own data types:

Outer collection class with inner collection:

```
public class Outer
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> InnerItems { get; set; }

    public bool HasItems  // <<< Add bool property next to inner collection
    {
        return Inner != null && InnerItems.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Outer collection property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Outer> OuterItems { get; set; }
```

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OuterItems}" />
```

Now you'll have a column called `HasItems` for each item in the outer collection that you can `Bind` to the `Icon.Visibility` property, or to a custom `BoolToImageSourceConverter` .

> I have ignored the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for this example.